# Is it possible to use an xsl:number as a variable?

Tags: xslt

I have this xsl:number :

```
<xsl:number level="single” count="numlitem[not(@revisionflag='deleted')]" from="numlist"/>
```

That I would like to use in a template like so :

```
<xsl:call-template name="dec-to-alpha">
    <xsl:with-param name="decimal" select="$MyNumber"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `xsl:with-param` allow a sequence constructor so you can always do

```
<xsl:with-param name="decimal">
   <xsl:number .../>
</xsl:with-param>
```

Furthermore, you can of course wrap your `xsl:number` into `xsl:variable`

```
<xsl:variable name="MyNumber">
  <xsl:number .../>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you use XSLT 2 or later adding an `as="xs:integer"` on the `xsl:variable` or `xsl:with-param` might be more efficient.